# Azure Deployment via Bitbucket

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, continuous-integration

I have a project on ASP.NET Web API that has references to many libraries. When we tried to do our usual CI/CD to the App Service via Deployment Center. We faced with issues.

We need to remove *.csproj* in order for the deployment to work else we are facing this error on server

> This project references NuGet package(s) that are missing on this computer. Use NuGet Package Restore to download them.  For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=322105.

However we require the *csproj* files for the various members in the team to work together for this particular project.

In this case, what is the likely solution that we can adopt?

Comment: What is your build script?

Comment: Could you publish the references inside this .csproj file? rather than removing the csproj you should be able to make your nuget references point to non-local sources

Comment: IMHO this is related to error thats explained in this (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-restore-troubleshooting#this-project-references-nuget-packages-that-are-missing-on-this-computer) document. Please read through it to understand the reason and resolution steps. Hope this pointer helps!! Cheers!!

Comment: Did you get a chance to remove all the locals file using the nogut command and then restore it , To add up if you could able to remove all the global packages and the cache file also then try to restore them would eventually update all the files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem:** The source control will only contain references for the binaries. The packages should be restored before a build can be triggered.

**Fix:** Add a step in your CI/CD to restore the NuGet packages in the project before you trigger a build. Ref attached image.

[image]